# ng-view not loading site on Android Chrome App

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-router

This question may have been asked before. But here goes:

My website is http://thecheeknee.com.

The site basic structure is as follows:

```
`index.html
js|-app.js
js|ctrls|pageLoad.js  -common controller for all pages
js|srvc|Datamap.js
templates/-about.html, etc`
```

The HTML basic view is as shown below:

```
<section ui-view></section>
```

The UI router angular code is as follows:

```
angular
.module('app',[
    'ui.router',
    'ngStorage'
    ])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider',function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home',{
            url:'/',
            templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
    controller:'pageLoad'
        })
```

The controller is very basic.

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('pageLoad',[ '$scope', 'Datamap', function($scope, Datamap){
    $scope.title = "thecheeknee";
    //$scope.$storage = $localStorage;
    //$scope.$storage.counter = $scope.$storage.counter+1 || 0;
    Datamap.getData().then(function(response){

  $scope.datamap = response.data;
});
```

The Data map service is as follows:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('Datamap', function($http) {
    //debugger;
    return{
      getData: function(){
        return $http.get('data/data.json',{ cache: true});
      }
    }
  });
```

The site works perfectly on the desktop across multiple browsers. But Chrome App on Android seems to load a blank page.
(I had designed the site to be responsive and had tested the UI thoroughly using Chrome's browser tool)

On observing, I noticed that the browser adds a **#!/** and loads the view into the page. On the mobile browser however, it seems to be stopping at the site name itself *(#!/ is not being added)*. So I assume the UI router is unable to load the route into the page.

I am relatively new to Angular, so is there anything minor I am missing out here?

Full source code at: https://github.com/thecheeknee/sitebase.git